# Programmatically replace data table or data field in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

In my company we have 1K+ Tableau workbooks, all using same Vertica data source via multiple-table connection or custom SQL. Often we end up in situation where reports stop working because underlying data source was changed: table renamed, field removed etc.

How can we proactively react to these changes is my question.

Can we try to correct source code of tableau workbooks to batch replace deprecated query parts?

Or can we monitor what data tables are used in the workbook with/without parsing the source code of the workbook to create alert system?

Thanks

Comment: I know of product that you could use. Interworks has something that allows you to do what you're asking. https://powertoolsfortableau.com/tools/workbook-tools-suite/

Comment: As an alternative to the product @Bernardo suggests - you may be able to do this trivially on your own. Each Tableau workbook file (.twb) is just XML. If you open one in a text editor you will see and, just like any text file, you can edit the content of it.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Bernardo - Indeed this is exactly what we need - https://powertoolsfortableau.com/tools/workbook-sdk . However $4999 per dev is too expensive in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Nicarus - it is the case but i don't think it's a trivial task however. Interworks is charging $4999 for it.  Do you have experience batch-editing workbooks?

Comment: @Yulia - I have actually done this work myself. You need to understand the basics of XML, explore the structure of the TWB file, and use your favorite programming language. I think once you look at the XML content, it becomes less intimidating of a task.